# assigning the uploaded file to the model property in loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, multer, body-parser

Good day,

I am new to node.js ecosystem so please excuse me for being a beginner. I basically want to configure loopback, bodyparser and multer to do one thing, i want the Phone.imageFile property to have value from the uploaded image file. posting my `Phone` model data through postman with body as form-data and no extra headers results in the following error.

```
"error": {
"name": "ValidationError",
"status": 422,
"message": "The `Phone` instance is not valid. Details: `imageFile` can't be blank (value: undefined).",
"statusCode": 422,
"details": {
  "context": "Phone",
  "codes": {
    "imageFile": [
      "presence"
    ]
  },
  "messages": {
    "imageFile": [
      "can't be blank"
    ]
  }
}
```

i can also verify that the image file is being uploaded to the **./phoneImageFiles/** folder through the following configuration. i can also say that the fields are properly read as the error message does not mention other required non-nullable fields

```
'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer({dest:'./phoneImageFiles/', }).single("imageFile"));
```

can somebody help me out? I tried doing the app.use() config i saw from searching through stackoverflow/google before but it seems that doing so is not valid because printing a console.log inside those does not seem to do nothing(maybe not being called)

github repo: https://github.com/silencer07/PinoyDroidMatch

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. after going away for a while I was able to find a way on how to do it. note that only admin access on my app uploads file so I opted to use memory storage, and they are only image files so I opted to store the buffer itself to the mongodb document(not a real life project anyway)

configure mutler:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();

app.use(multer({storage : storage, }).single("imageFile"));
```

configure before remote hook:

```
Phone.beforeRemote('**', function (ctx, unused, next) {
    var req = ctx.req;

    //uploaded using multer
    if(req.file){
        var imageFile = req.file.buffer;
        var fileName = req.file.originalname;
        console.log("uploaded file:" + fileName);
        var imageFileType = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length);

        req.body.imageFile = imageFile;
        req.body.imageFileType = imageFileType;            
    }
    next();
});
```

Regards